# Cannot connect to samba

Tags: windows-7, debian, samba

Im currently facing a problem connection to samba. I have used samba for some time now and the hasent been any problems until now.

When i call smbclient -L localhost -U samba samba returns...
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

No matter what i do i cant seem to get this to work, trying to log in from Win7 poses the same problem

Im using version 3.5.6

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general login failure error. Did you create a linux user and also run "smbpasswd -a -U [username]"?

Comment: It seems like the smbpasswd is not included in version 3.6.5, which is part of the problem.

Maybe im missing something here.

Thanks